# How to evaluate the json response from google's JSON/Atom Custom Search API by using php?

Tags: php, json

How to evaluate the json response from google's JSON/Atom Custom Search API by using php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use json_decode to convert the response into an object you can iterate through

http://php.net/json_decode

From PHP's site for that function:

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

Comment: Sure! I updated the code for you. The link I posted originally has several other great examples.

Comment: oh this is a common example.I tried it already with the result returned from the google api but doesn't work.finally i did xml serialiazation by converting that json to xml